# mysql get the sum of two Columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to get the total of two columns in sql as shown below

```
SELECT sum(aaanum) aaa, sum(bbbnum) bbb, sum(aaa+bbb) ccc
FROM myTable;
```

However when I do this I get **Unknown column 'aaa' in 'field list'**

When I do it like this I get the result I expect

```
SELECT sum(aaanum) aaa, sum(bbbnum) bbb, sum(aaanum+bbbnum) ccc
FROM myTable;
```

However I want to do it like I have done in the first example as what I have put in for the sample code is quite simple I want to be able to apply this to more complex examples without having the repetition as this will be hard to maintain if any changes are made I will have to change it in two places.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: This has been asked many many many times before

Comment: @Lamak sorry about the duplicate.  I have elbeen looking but musn't have had the right search ferms thanks for the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest you can get is a query on the query:

```
SELECT
  aaa,
  bbb,
  aaa+bbb ccc
FROM (
  SELECT
    sum(aaanum) aaa,
    sum(bbbnum) bbb
  FROM myTable
) x
```

FYI the "x" at the end is an alias for the result of the inner query, and it required to be syntactically correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
Select a, b, sum(a+b)
from (select sum(aaanum) a, sum(bbbnum)
      from mytable)
group by a, b
```

Just need to compute the sums first in a sub select.